# c++ get directory path, parse folder name, and print file content from parent directory

Tags: c++, boost

While using a simulator and opening a terminal within a node, I need to read a file from the parent directory that starts with the current directory name. The structure is the following:

```
/path/to/directory/session#/node.conf
                      |
                      |_node.xy
```

I can get the current path (as well as the parent path) `/path/to/directory/session#/node.conf` using the boost library.

```
std::string cwd = getcwd(NULL, 0);
boost::filesystem::path p1(cwd);
... p1.parent_path()
```

I'm not familiar with Boost, but I would like to get the folder name only `node.conf`, parse to get `node`, navigate to the parent directory and read from a file called `node.xy`.

What is the best way to do it? I looked for other questions here but couldn't find one that worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boost Filesystem is rich with methods. There are many ways to do the same thing. Always keep the docs handy, you will need them.

[Documentation Links](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm#Documentation)

[Reference Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html)

So:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main( )
{
    namespace bfs= boost::filesystem;

    bfs::path p1( "/path/to/directory/session#/node.conf" );
    bfs::path target( p1.parent_path( ) / "_node.xy" );
    std::cout << target << std::endl;
    //or
    bfs::path targ2( p1 );
    targ2.remove_filename( );
    targ2/= "_node.xy";
    std::cout << targ2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```